# Tratamento "escape" em query (escape de caracteres)

Tags: php, mysql

#### Cenário:

Query da inserção:

```
public function forward($descricao)
{
    ($descricao == '') ? $descricao = 'NULL' : $descricao = "'{$descricao}'" ;
    $sql_enc = " INSERT INTO rg_encaminhamentos (`descricao`) VALUES ($descricao) ";

}
```

Estou inserindo no texto (no caso na `$descricao`):

```
SET UF = 18
WHERE DOCUMENTO IN (SELECT HANDLE FROM DOCUMENTOS
WHERE DOCUMENTODIGITADO IN ('218747','218748','218786','218787','218794',
'218795','218839','218840','218885','218886','218914','218915'))
```

---

#### Problema:

O erro na query ocorre, pois **o texto é reconhecido como parte do código**.

---

#### Dúvida:

- **Quais as possíveis formas** para tratar isso?

Comment: Experimenta isto: `$sql_enc = " INSERT INTO tabela (`descricao`) VALUES ('$descricao') ";`, com as pelicas em `$descricao` (`'$descricao'`)

Comment: Não deu... mas eu tenho um tratamento antes porque esse campo pode ser NULL também... vou colocar no código, desculpa.

Comment: Porque `'NULL'` é como se fosse uma string, tem que ser `NULL` sem aspas! Você poderia e deveria utilizar `mysqli` ou `pdo`.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim, o NULL está ok... acho que resolvi... inverti as aspas `'"{$descricao}"'`

Comment: Com uma resposta logo abaixo, você também pode responde suas próprias perguntas

Comment: Encontrei ! até tinha excluído a pergunta ! 
Obrigado pessoal !

Comment: Mas, explique melhor isso... tem baixa qualidade sua resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido com o comando `addslashes`:

```
public function forward($descricao){

   $descricao = addslashes($descricao);

   ($descricao == '') ? $descricao = 'NULL' : $descricao = "'{$descricao}'";

   $sql_enc = " INSERT INTO rg_encaminhamentos (`descricao`) VALUES ($descricao) ";
}
```

O comando adiciona as barras para escapar os caracteres.

Manual oficial:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php